# Simple way to validate command line arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

How to check if argv (argument vector) contains a char, i.e.: A-Z

Would like to make sure that argv only contains unsigned intergers

For example:

```
if argv[1] contained "7abc7\0" - ERROR

if argv[1] contains "1234\0" - OK
```

Comment: @stefant: add a tag titled: windows

Comment: Should have done! will do next time :)

Comment: Nah: best to do it - because some developers might not be clear as to what platform - linux/windows etc. Just "edit" then write "windows" for a tag...

Comment: Ohh, didnt know you could do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 bool isuint(char const *c) {
   while (*c) {
     if (!isdigit(*c++)) return false;
   }
   return true;
 }

 ...
 if (isuint(argv[1])) ...
```

Additional error checking could be done for a NULL c pointer and an empty string, as desired.

**update**: (added the missing c++)

Comment: Nice one, i knew there must have been a way.

Comment: Wouldn't that need a c++?  while (*c) { if (!isdigit(*c++)) ... }  (no pun intended!)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
const std::string numbers="0123456789";

for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
  if(std::string(argv[i]).find_first_not_of(numbers)!=std::string::npos)
    // error, act accordingly
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet591.htm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int number = 0;
  cout << "Enter an integer: ";
  cin >> number;
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');

  if (!cin || cin.gcount() != 1)
    cout << "Not a numeric value.";
  else
    cout << "Your entered number: " << number;
  return 0;
}
```

Modified, of course, to operate on argv instead of cin.

This may not be exactly what you want though - run a few tests on it and check the output if you don't understand what it does.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

A much more flexible approach (ie: probably more than what you are asking for in your question) but is still very easy to use is using [getopts](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Getopt.html) which is part libc

Comment: @hharez: But is not standard C++?

Comment: On what platform are you working on? If you have the gnu libc then it will work.

Comment: Windows (Win32) - I tend to use it when programming in C (linux)

Comment: I don't beleive the gnu libc is availble for Win32 is it? If not then there it is not available unless there is an equivelant, but for linux c or c++ development it is there for sure

Comment: No its not. But there are alternatives - see: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=393293 ( cool! :) )

Comment: Ummm...I don't see any way to specify that a parameter must meet certain characteristics (all-numeric, for instance). I don't think getopt actually solves the problem at hand!